# error saving image on my web server with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create so I can upload photos to my website with php but the code I'm using doesn't show me the image once it's uploaded to my web server; I don't know what could go wrong...

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php

$imagenCodificada = file_get_contents("https://i.imgur.com/FNJn8FA.png");
if(strlen($imagenCodificada) <= 0) exit("No se recibió ninguna imagen");

$imagenCodificadaLimpia = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", urldecode($imagenCodificada));


$imagenDecodificada = base64_decode($imagenCodificadaLimpia);


$nombreImagenGuardada = "foto_" . uniqid() . ".png";


file_put_contents($nombreImagenGuardada, $imagenDecodificada);


exit($nombreImagenGuardada);
?>
```

Blank image appears

How could I upload the image without it appearing blank?

Thank you very much in advance!

Could someone help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Well, your code does not really output any image. It only loads, converts and saves something to a file. And finally you output the name of a file you created.

Comment: And how could I save the image on my website? I'm new at this

Comment: Try to use realpath. it saving i think the path could be wrong 

e:g: `$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));`
Then `$nombreImagenGuardada = $path . "/foto_" . uniqid() . ".png";` 
Finally save it